# How to Fetch Value from Joomla 2.5 Database Column, Field Name & Value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, joomla

I am trying to create a condition in which basis

> Column Name
>   Field Name
>   Field Value

of mysql database, a conditional script should show in - Attached Table
[image]

ColumnName - FormId
Fieldname - Listing
Fieldvalue - Listing Value

Below is script

```
$max = 1;
$listing = JRequest::getInt('listing');

if($listing) {
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery("SELECT COUNT(`SubmissionId`) FROM #__rsform_submission_values WHERE `FormId`='".(int) $formId."' AND `FieldName`='listing' AND `FieldValue`='".$listing."' ");
$nrSub = $db->loadResult();

if ($nrSub >= $max) {
  $formLayout = '<p>Sorry, no more submissions are accepted for this car.</p>';
}
}
```

I think am messing up with Fieldvalue column - may be it might not be able to fetch in value. Can someone help and advise pls

Comment: You are quering count `COUNT(`SubmissionId`)`, you have to use column names if you need values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are Quering count, it should be column names or `*` for all columns, if you need values, see example below:

```
$db->setQuery("SELECT * FROM #__rsform_submission_values WHERE `FormId`='".(int) $formId."' AND `FieldName`='listing' AND `FieldValue`='".$listing."' ");
$nrSub = $db->loadAssocList();
print_r($nrSub);
```

Additionally, Please go through with for ref [Joomla DB Documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase)

**EDIT:**

```
$Query = "SELECT 
    COUNT(`SubmissionId`) SubmissionCount, `FormId`, `FieldName`, `FieldValue` 
    FROM #__rsform_submission_values 
    WHERE `FormId`='".(int) $formId."' AND `FieldName`='listing' AND `FieldValue`='".$listing."'
    GROUP BY `FormId`, `FieldName`, `FieldValue`";
$db->setQuery($Query);
$nrSub = $db->loadAssocList();
print_r($nrSub);
```

Comment: Hello - Yes Count would be used to find total submissions based on matching parameters (Form Id, Field name, Field Value) and comparing it with maximum value of 1 as defined in query.

Comment: @Ruchika Please add, what should be desired results

Comment: Hello, Count should happen to Table basis matching - 'Form Id' & 'Listing Field' and 'Listing Field Value'. If a duplicate count is attempted to be submitted then a message should be shown - Sorry, no more submissions are accepted for this car.

Comment: @Ruchika see my updated answer, hope this is what you need! You may add more columns in `SELECT` / `GROUP BY` clause as per need.

Comment: Your code looks perfectly fine. Thanks - but i guess problem is in this line - $listing = JRequest::getInt('listing');

if($listing) { . It seems that listing value is not getting imported in it

Comment: you can debug it a bit, check if value is actually posted, also use Jinput as suggested in joomla docs https://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput

or just, `print_r($_REQUEST);` to see what values are available on what keys, for debugging purpose

Comment: Sure would work up accordingly. thanks for help. Basis kind assistance - marking reply as answer, though i have to work a bit on the code part